# Django: Link two models with common foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Im new to django and im currently making an admin panel where i can view user orders.

I handle my orders based on the following OrderItem Model

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and their shipping info in the follwing ShippingAdress model

```
class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

Views.py

```
orders=OrderItem.objects.select_related('customer')
 context={
        'orders':orders,        
    }

 return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

and in my html i want to print each customer's ShippingAdress data.
Im thinking something like the following but im stuck and it doesnt work.

```
{% for order in orders %}

  <td>{{order.customer.address}}</td>
  <td>{{order.customer.city}}</td>

{% endfor %}
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: The address and city aren't showing up because your `User` model probably don't have the `address` and `city` fields. You can 1) override the `User` model to have the shipping address fields or 2) use reverse relation of the customer to get the `ShippingAddress` objects of the user using the `related_name` attribute, which in your case is `shippingaddress_set` by default. However with the latter method, there is the assumption that a customer can have multiple shipping addresses due to the `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `related_name` to your `ShippingAddress`

```
class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
customer = models.ForeignKey(
    User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name="addresses")
```

and use it in your template like that

```
<td>{{order.customer.addresses.first.address}}</td>
```

with `first` you get the first address and with `all` all of them.

Comment: thank you very much. Can you please explain how this works?, i mean how the ```OrderItem model``` connects with the ```ShippingAddress model```. We dont define it anywhere

Comment: with User model, in ShippingAddress and OrderItem you have a customer ( User instance ) each order instance has a customer, and each customer has multiple addresses... Django ORM is so powerful for more information I recommend read docs